# Is it possible to open embedded flow (minibrowser) in the in the same mobile browser tab?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am implementing an ASP - MVC4 hybrid website. The desktop browser flow works fine. I am trying to get the redirection to PayPal working in the mobile website and after much reading on the forums I am running out of options and ideas. I have tried calling the redirection from the controller to the minibrowser link, this seems to work fine until it has to return... it never does… .. this solution is mentioned in
[Paypal Adaptive payment for mobile web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463389/paypal-adaptive-payment-for-mobile-web),…

`var url = Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
                ? string.Concat(payUrlConfig, "webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=", payKey, "&expType=mini")
                : string.Concat(payUrlConfig, "webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=", payKey);
            return Redirect(url);`

The second option is the one mentioned in [Paypal Embedded Flow not using returnUrl or cancelUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860161/paypal-embedded-flow-not-using-returnurl-or-cancelurl). That returns fine but it needs to actually open another tab in the mobile browser which by default will have pop ups turned off. I don’t want to go through the exercise of asking people to modify their browser settings so my site can work. 
I couldn’t find any documentation on  PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini object. Is there any configuration I can pass to the object so the redirection happens on the same tab, pretty much the same behaviour as the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey.. 
Or is there other way to implement this and I just have been unable to find it?
Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated